# How to detect if a person score hits 0?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a PVP server on Xbox One, and I need a command to put into a command block to detect if a person hits the score of 0 because 0 means that they left the game, and I need a way to delete that user, "Offline Player" from the scoreboard

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a way to detect the score of 0, `/execute if entity @a[scores={<score>=0}] run <command>`. But, if you want to detect if a player left the game, you can do these commands instead:

`/scoreboard objectives add leftGame minecraft.custom:minecraft.leave_game`

And these in repeating command blocks:

`/execute if entity @a[scores={leftGame=1}] run <command>`

`/scoreboard players set @a leftGame 0`

Edit: To reset a scoreboard, use /scoreboard players reset

Answer (score 0):

The way on Xbox is `@a [scores ={*SCORE NAME*=0}]`, (EX: `/tag @a [scores ={Level=0}] add) Zero`, other one is for Java Edition.